# How can I write a regex that will allow space and limit number of characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some validation in my Model. For the Society Name:

1. Only Letters, Upper and Lower Case.
2. No numbers.
3. Must allow for Camel Case
4. Allow for Spaces between words.
5. Limited from 1-16 characters.

Code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Society Name is required.")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "The {0} has a maximum of {1} characters.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z][0-9]{16}$", ErrorMessage = "Society Name field requires 1-16 Alphabetical characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Society Name *")]
    public string SocietyName { get; set; }
```

Comment: In the Regex how can I meet those requirements.

Comment: Maybe you should write some examples of valid and invalid input?

Comment: It helps if you put a question into the question. I've done it for you.

Comment: If you says that numbers are not allowed then remove the [0-9]. Change the Regex to`^[A-Za-z\s]{1,16}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually allow spaces and lowercase letters, right now, those patterns are not even present in your current regex. Also, you used `[0-9]` that matches digits, although numbers should not be matched as per your requirements.

To match lower- and uppercase letters or/and whitespace chars, you may use

```
^[A-Za-z\s]{1,16}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0NNNBa/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z\s]{1,16}` - 1 to 16 ASCII letters or/and whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

If you only want to allow 1 space between words, use

```
^(?=.{1,16}$)[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0NNNBa/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,16}$)` - the string length can be 1 to 16
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\s` - 1 whitespace
  - `[A-Za-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.